# MySQL - Return the last record on the second table then return all in the first table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables customers and orders, below is the structure.

Table - contacts

```
id
```

Table - orders

```
id
contact_id
```

How can I select all from contacts table but only select the latest record from the orders table?

```
SELECT contacts.*, 
       Max(orders.id) 
FROM   contacts 
       LEFT JOIN orders 
              ON contacts.id = orders.contact_id 
GROUP  BY contacts.id;
```

But I always gets `NULL` if I use `LEFT JOIN`, it only have value if I use `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select the latest record in orders and group it first

```
select contacts.*, orders.id
from contacts
left join (select max(id) as id, contact_id
           from orders
           group by contact_id) orders
     on contacts.id = orders.contact_id
```

Comment: Still returning NULL, only having value if I use inner join and right join

Comment: @richersoon, could you give us your expected output? Here is my sample http://rextester.com/RZSB59922

Comment: Apparantenly mysql only configured to return 1000, so I am not able to see the other data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use UNION like

```
select * from orders order by id desc limit 1
UNION
select * from contacts
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to aggregate max value with all columns from contacts table, add all columns from contacts table after group by function

Comment: Can you please give me sample

Comment: Ya sure. Add all the columns names nest to group by function

Answer (score 0):

I trust the answer provided by Alex should work well. The following query shall list all records from contacts and the last id from orders table.

```
SELECT 
   c.*, 
   (SELECT Max(o.id) FROM orders  o 
    INNER JOIN contacts c1 ON o.id=c1.id
    )as last_order_id
FROM contacts c
```